# How to install Ubuntu on Raspberry pi zero W?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, pi

I have Raspberry Pi Zero W. And need to install Ubuntu on it. [Here](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) There is nothing mentioned for RPI zero w. So I installed *.img* of Ubunut 22.04(tried both desktop and server ) but it didn't work.
Can you help me to find the proper Ubuntu version for RPI Zero W?
Or maybe in general there is no Ubuntu version supported by RPI zero w.

Comment: SO is strictly for questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.). You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Comment: What's the objection to using the dedicated, designed for Raspberry Pi, Raspberry Pi OS (based on Debian) like everyone else?